# How can i format the total number of hours in Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

How can I format the **total time per day** to **10:00** and not with the decimal point.

[image: x]

[image]

I also tried to **Format** the **Number** to **Duration** ends up changing the total value.

[image]

Best regards.

Comment: What spreadsheet app are you using? I'm asking because one question is about Google Sheets but you mention that the options shown aren't available to you and there is another answer that is about Excel.

Comment: Can you provide a few more details?  Are the TimeIn and TimeOut values always within the same day, ie the difference is never greater than 23:59 (in hours:minutes)?  Can you provde a sample sheet with few more data rows, and the results you want, formated as you'd like?  It seems that the custom number format of h:mm is giving the desired result you want, at least in my testing.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want a decimal value, remove the *24 from the formula
and see if that works? Optional, if you don't want the seconds to show, use a custom number format as described above.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't make sense. I still don't get the accurate value

Comment: Well, it does seem to be working fine for me. Maybe share a copy of your spreadsheet so I can have a closer look.

Answer (score 1):

With the Time-in in **C2** and Time-out in **D2**, in **E2** enter:

```
=D2-C2
```

and format as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In **Google Sheets** you have to select a cell you want to format, and then:

menu *Format > Number > More Formats > Custom number formats*

[image]

Or you can click on 123 icon (More formats) and select on drop down menu *More Formats > Custom number formats*

[image]